# How to keep typing in the terminal after 'python manage.py runserver' in Django?

Tags: django, macos, terminal

I was following along [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4&t=28m36s) tutorial on Django until minute 28:36 when the teacher uses a quick shortcut that appeared as **^C(trydjango) $** on the terminal, allowing him to continue typing to ***makemigrations*** after he did ***runserver***.

When I try to type in the terminal after ***python manage.py runserver***, the enter button does not submit the commands, but rather enters down to a newline making me stuck. I am unsure how to continue with the tutorial, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is not the case. He used Ctrl+C (this is the origin of the `^C` to stop the server).

Comment: The `$` at the end of the command starts the process in the background

Comment: So when you want to 'makemigrations' you must stop the server to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> allowing him to continue typing to makemigrations after he did runserver.

That is *not* the case. He used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (this is the origin of the `^C` to stop the server).

[<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) is a seqeuence that will raise a [`SIGINT` signal [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#SIGINT) to the process that is running, telling it you want it to interupt. Most processes will then try to stop running (for example after doing some tasks to store the state of the program).

In a lot of terminals however, you can make use of multiple tabs where one of the tabs is used to run the server whereas others are used to check files, the database, etc. On the Mac OS X Terminal Emulator, you can use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, whereas on LXTerminal and a lot of other Linux terminal emulators, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: So when you want to 'makemigrations' you must stop 'runserver' to do so?

Comment: @ismodes: well in the Youtube tutorial it does happen. I think you can use multiple tabs/terminals to do it simultanously, but since restarting the server does not take that much time, it will likely not allow you to work much faster anyway.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes sense. So it does not matter if the server is running (runserver) or if it isn't to 'makemigrations,' right? 'makemigrations' is independent of 'runserver' or could there be conflict between the two?

Comment: @ismodes: normally not, since it is an independent process that checks differences and makes migration files accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hows it going,

You just need to open a second terminal, and leave that one running.
If youre using VSCode or PyCharm then you can just click the plus beside the terminal at the bottom and add another.